# kafka-0.9 cann't consumer data

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

i use the 0.9 version of Kafka to consumer data, but the program always run to the line of consumer.poll(100), then it does not continue running. and i use the jar of kafka-clients-0.9.0.0.
kafka: kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0
zookeeper: zookeeper-3.4.5

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "10.28.176.11:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("tmp"));
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("start comsuming...");
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
            System.out.println("start print data.......");
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        }
    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

the log:

[image]

Comment: as i use the method mentioning here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770024/kafka-0-9-0-1-java-consumer-stuck-in-awaitmetadataupdate),set the variables ADVERTISED_PORT and ADVERTISED_HOST , but it still gets stuck on the consumer.poll call.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out. i deleted all kafka metadata in zookeeper,such as /borkers /admin /comsumers /config /controller /controller_epoch /isr_change_notification, then restarted the kafka, The mistake is gone. i think maybe the kafka cluster have some errors.