# Apache Kafka Java consumer does not receive message for topic with replication factor more than one

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm starting on Apache Kakfa with a simple Producer, Consumer app in Java. I'm using `kafka-clients` version `0.10.0.1` and running it on a Mac.

I created a topic named `replicated_topic_partitioned` with 3 partitions and with replication factor as 3.

I started the zookeeper at port 2181. I started three brokers with id 1, 2 and 3 on ports 9092, 9093 and 9094 respectively.

Here's the output of the describe command

```
kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic replicated_topic_partitioned --bootstrap-server localhost:9092    
Topic:replicated_topic_partitioned    PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:3    Configs:segment.bytes=1073741824
     Topic: replicated_topic_partitioned    Partition: 0    Leader: 3    Replicas: 3,1,2    Isr: 3,1,2
     Topic: replicated_topic_partitioned    Partition: 1    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,2,3    Isr: 1,2,3
     Topic: replicated_topic_partitioned    Partition: 2    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,3,1    Isr: 2,3,1
```

I wrote a simple producer and a consumer code. The producer ran successfully and published the messages. But when I start the consumer, the poll call just waits indefinitely. On debugging, I found that it keeps on looping at the awaitMetadataUpdate method on the ConsumerNetworkClient.

Here are the code for Producer and Consumer

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

KafkaProducer<String, String> myProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
DateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
String topic = "replicated_topic_partitioned";

int numberOfRecords = 10;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
       String message = String.format("Message: %s  sent at %s", Integer.toString(i), dtFormat.format(new Date()));
       System.out.println("Sending " + message);
       myProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, message));

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    myProducer.close();
}
```

Consumer.java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  
properties.put("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> myConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);

String topic = "replicated_topic_partitioned";
myConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

try {
    while (true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = myConsumer.poll(1000);
         printRecords(records);
    }
 } finally {
     myConsumer.close();
 }
```

Adding some key-fields from `server.properties`

```
broker.id=1 
host.name=localhost
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

The server.properties for the other two brokers was a replica of the above with broker.id, the port and thelog.dirs changed.

This did not work for me:
[Kafka 0.9.0.1 Java Consumer stuck in awaitMetadataUpdate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770024/kafka-0-9-0-1-java-consumer-stuck-in-awaitmetadataupdate)

---

But, if I start the consumer from the command line passing a partition, it successfully reads the messages for that partition. But it does not receive any message when *just* a topic is specified.

Works:

```
kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic replicated_topic_partitioned --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 
     --from-beginning --partition 1
```

Does not work:

```
kafka_2.12-2.3.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic replicated_topic_partitioned --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 
    --from-beginning
```

**NOTE:** The above consumer works perfectly for a topic with replication factor equals 1.

Question:

1. Why does the Java Producer not read any message for topic with replication factor more than one (even when assigning it to a partition) (like `myConsumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(new TopicPartition(topic, 2)`)?
2. Why does the console consumer read message only when passed a partition  (again works for a topic with replication factor of one)

Comment: _" But it does not work when just a topic is specified."_ - By _"does not work"_ what do you mean? Does it fail?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous It does not receive any message. Updated my question clarifying this

Comment: Do you know how many messages does each of the partitions have?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I sent a total of 10 messages. They got distributed to the partitions - I'm saying this  by the console consumer output when passed `--partition` 0,1 and 2. Why would the number of messages per partition be of any interest here?

Comment: And have you tried `ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost` and `ADVERTISED_PORT=9092` without any luck?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Yes. Adding them did not make any difference to me.

Comment: Can you also share the configuration in `server.properties`?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I read somewhere stating the importance of `group.id` and the consumer not being closed properly. Could that be a reason? My initital runs had the `group.id` as empty string. But, it is not consuming messages even after changing to a UUID.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I have added it to my question. Thanks

Comment: In `server.properties` have you tried setting `advertised.host.name="localhost"` and `advertised.port=9092` ?

Comment: I had `advertised.host.name=localhost` and `advertised.port=9092` in my properties (without quotes - I guess that shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: how do you know produce succeeds? to you examine the returned future? do you provide a callback? do you call flush() on the producer ?

Comment: @radai I don't call flush. I can see the messages from the *console consumer* when reading from a partition.

Comment: Can you try `myProducer.flush();` before the close?

Comment: @user7 - youre setting the exact same key on all records. i think they are all hashing into the same partition (which just isnt partition 1) ...

Answer (score 1):

so, youre sending 10 records, but all 10 records have the SAME key:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
   String message = String.format("Message: %s  sent at %s", Integer.toString(i), dtFormat.format(new Date()));
   System.out.println("Sending " + message);
   myProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, message)); <--- KEY=topic
}
```

unless told otherwise (by setting a partition directly on the `ProducerRecord`) the partition into which a record is delivered is determine by something like:

> partition = murmur2(serialize(key)) % numPartitions

so same key means same partition.

have you tried searching for your 10 records on partitions 0 and 2 maybe?

if you want a better "spread" of records amongst partitions, either use a null key (you'd get round robin) or a variable key.

Comment: I suppose this cannot be true. Internally, when I do not pass a key, it defaults to the key as `null`. It should use a round-robin in that case. Also, when I run the console producer by passing topic **and** partition, it retrives the messages for all partitions (0, 1 and 2). My issue is that the Java consumer does not retrive the messages.

Comment: The issue is not happening now after a restart. It must have something to do with the deletion and re-creation of the `kafka-logs`. See my answer (not an answer really)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is **not** an answer.

The Java consumer is now working as expected. I did not do any change to the code or the configuration. The only thing I did was to restart my Mac. This caused the `kafka-logs` folder (and the `zookeeper` folder too I guess) to be deleted.

I re-created the topic (with the same command - 3 partitions, replication factor of 3). Then re-started the brokers with the **same** configuration - no `advertised.host.name` or `advertised.port` config.

So, recreation of the kafka-logs and topics remediated something that was causing an issue earlier.

---

My only suspect is a non-properly terminated consumer. I ran the consumer code without the `close` call on the consumer in the *finally* block initially. I also had the same `group.id`. Maybe, all 3 partitions were assigned to consumers that weren't properly terminated or closed. This is just a guess..

But even calling `myConsumer.position(new TopicPartition(topic, 2))` did not return a response earlier when I assigned the consumer to a partition. It was looping in the same `awaitMetadataUpdate` method.